# Date value being reduced by 1 when the client and the server are in different time zones

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the code below to get a date value from a jQuery datepicker.

```
function GetViewModelData() {
var actionViewModel = [];
var rowCount = $('#myDynamicTable tbody tr').length;
var actionDate;

for (i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++) {
            actionDate = document.getElementsByClassName("txtDateOfAction")[i - 1].value;         
            var parts = actionDate.split("/");
            var dt = new Date(parseInt(parts[2], 10), parseInt(parts[1], 10) - 1, parseInt(parts[0], 10));

            var rdtViewModel = new DetailsViewModel(0, dt);
            actionViewModel.push(rdtViewModel);
        }

    var obj = new ReportViewModel(0, actionViewModel);
    var viewmodel = JSON.stringify(obj);
    return viewmodel;
}
```

I'm then using the code below to send my value to an SQL server database.

```
var SubmitData = function() {
    $(".btnSave").click(function() {
        Loader();
        var viewmodel = GetViewModelData();
        var actionCode = $.trim($("#actionCode").val()).toLowerCase();

        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: viewmodel,
            headers: GetRequestVerificationToken(),
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/' + virtualDirectory + '/Submission/Save',
            success: function(data) {
                $("#divMaster").html(data);
                return false;
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert("An error occured");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The problem i'm facing is that if the client and the server are in different time zones, the date value the client selected is reduced by 1 when being saved on the server.

For example, if the client selects 19/01/2017, it is saved as 18/01/2017 on the server (in the database).

If the client is in the same time zone as the server, every things works fine.

How can resolve this issue?

Comment: Use UTC, not local time.